# Limit elementSelectField to specific sections

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, form

How do I limit this elementSelectField to only allow entries within a certain section?

```
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
  label: 'Blog post',
  name: 'blogpost',
  elementType: 'craft\\elements\\Entry',
  selectionLabel: 'Select your blog post',
  showSiteMenu: true,
  limit: 1,
  required: true
}) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is very little documentation around this. Use `criteria` like this. I've also tested `siteId` which worked. I'm sure there are more criterias available.

```
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
  label: 'Blog post',
  name: 'blogpost',
  elementType: 'craft\\elements\\Entry',
  selectionLabel: 'Select your blog post',
  showSiteMenu: true,
  criteria: {
      section: ['blogposts'],
      siteId: 1
  },
  limit: 1,
  required: true
}) }}
```

[Link to the relevant Craft CMS source code.](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/60881865f1b680c5aa5d4ad8f56d9a1ce3e452b0/src/fields/BaseRelationField.php#L843)